# "libRestKit.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (armv7)"

Tags: ios, xcode, restkit, gpuimage, xcodebuild

I'm trying to use xcodebuild to build a project, but `RestKit` and `GPUImage` are giving issues below:

> ld: warning: ignoring file /project/libGPUImage.a, missing required architecture armv7 in file /project/libGPUImage.a (2 slices)
>
> ld: warning: ignoring file /project/libRestKit.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (armv7): /project/libRestKit.a

Please help!

Comment: if you solved this plz post answer I m having same problem.

Answer (score 8):

Set `Build Active Architecture Only` to `NO` for static Library in project target setting.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are not using latest versions of the libraries, though I am not sure about this that the latest one supports `armv7`, any way try the following shown in the image below

[image]

I hope it works.

Cheers.