# Flex native extension for iOS packaging error

Tags: ios, apache-flex, package, flash-builder, ane

I am trying to make a native extension in AIR for a receipt printer in iOS.
When I try to package my application using Flash Builder 4.7 (on windows 8.1), I get this error message:

Error occurred while packaging the application:

ld: file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (armv7): C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\cfb2713d-1d55-4db3-b645-f5e8b4a58f36/libcom.domain.printer.a for architecture armv7

Compilation failed while executing : ld64

Please help !

Comment: possible duplicate of [file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (i386)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10803211/file-was-built-for-archive-which-is-not-the-architecture-being-linked-i386)

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14828693/error-file-was-built-for-archive-which-is-not-the-architecture-being-linked-a and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24669336/librestkit-a-file-was-built-for-archive-which-is-not-the-architecture-being-li